# How to apply .diff and .patch file by SSH?

Tags: version-control, ssh

I use Drupal 7 and I read every article about applying patches, but I don't understand how to apply patches to Drupal files using SSH. I am administrator of a Linux server that hosts a Drupal site.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference to patching on a local machine to patching on your server, providing they use the same software. Either way there's nothing Drupal can help with specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After logging in to your site with SSH, in order to apply patches, you should have or install a program on your server. `patch` is the most widespread one, but you can also use `git` for it.

You can find more documentation on applying patches in the Drupal site: https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply

Comment: So git or patch must be installed on my linux host ? where are the patch and git installation files?

Comment: As mentioned by @Clive above, your question might be better placed at a Linux-specific Q&A site, maybe superuser.com? Installing standard software, such as patch or git, on a Linux server and using it is not Drupal-specific.